# Is it possible to get the Collection using reflection if i have the member of collection?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I have a sample Entity Student as below.

```
 public class Student
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        private int _credits;
        public int Credits
        {
            get
            {
                return _credits;
            }
            set
            {
                _credits = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

I have another Class which is descendent of  System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection as below.

```
   public class StudentCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Student>
    {
        //SomeCollection level validations.
    }
```

Now I am creating the student Collection Like `StudentCollection c1 = new StudentCollection();`.
The question is If I have a student object which is the member of c1 collection then is it possible to get the complete collection to which the object belongs to Using Reflection? 
If its not possible using reflection then is there some other way out through which the above is possible.

Comment: _"Is it possible to the collection..."_ What is possible? Why you need reflection at all? That should be the very last resort.

Comment: No, the reference is only one way `StudentCollection` -> `Student`. You need a direct reference to the collection to determine the collections content.

Comment: If you need it provide a property `StudentCollection Collection` and initialize it from  constructor

Comment: How can I get a direct reference to the collection to determine the collections content. @thehennyy

Comment: Property in student class or StudentCollection Class? @TimSchmelter

Comment: The collection doesn't need one because it knows already which students are there. But the student doesn't know in which collection he is.

Comment: Most collection classes aren't exclusive - objects may be placed in *multiple* collections. There are some specialised exceptions (e.g. `SqlParameterCollection`/`SqlParameter`) but in such cases the contained objects are specifically coded to be container aware

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean, given an instance (e.g. `Student student`), Can I get the collection that the instance belongs to.

If so, the answer is no, not using just the student.

If you have multiple collections (e.g. `List<StudentCollection> studentCollections`) then you could search through them all to find the list that contains the instance.

```
var collection = studentCollections.Where(collection => collection.Contains(student)).SingleOrDefault();
```

collection will then be either the collection that contains the student or null if there was no match.
The performance could be pretty awful if the collections get large though. In that case you would want to look into some sort of indexing, possibly using Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is probably not what you want.

If you have the "item" you could iterate through all objects in scope, and if the object is a collection, check if the collection contains the item using `Collection.Contains(item)`. Note that there could be multiple collections holding the same item.

This will be a very costly operation and pretty complex to implement, so most likely not appropriate for your purpose, unless you are making some kind of debugging tool or similar.

If you have a limited number of "candidate" collections, you can check if any of them contains the item by calling `Collection.Contains(item)`.